# correlate a demographic column with answers from multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, statistics

I have a spreadsheet from a Google Consumer Survey. The survey captured demographics as well as the responses to a question. Acceptable responses could have chosen zero or more 'answers'. The response for each answer is in a unique column. For example,

---

user id | gender |  age  | income | answer 1 | answer 2 | answer 3 |

---

0001    | Female | 20-30 | 50-75  | [empty]  |  Right   |  Never   |

---

0002    | Male   | 20-30 | 30-50  |  Up      |  Left    |  [empty] |

---

I would like to know how to correlate a column of demographic info with each of the possible answers. For example, I want to be able to answer questions like, `Were males more likely than females to choose X for answer 1?` and `Which age group was more likely to choose Y for answer 2?`

I prefer an answer using Google Sheets functions, but I am open to learning other ways to understand the data. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good way is to use `query` function. Let's first assume, your data is stored in range `A:G`:

```
    A   |    B   |   C |    D   |     E    |     F    |     G    |
user id | gender | age | income | answer 1 | answer 2 | answer 3 |    
0001    | Female |20-30|  50-75 | [empty]  | Right    |   Never  |    
0002    | Male   |20-30|  30-50 |    Up    | Left     |  [empty] |
```

you may write simple query functions.

For example, to count all answer 1, group them by gender and age, pivot by answer 1:

```
=query(A:G,"select B, C, count(D) where not A is null group by B, C pivot E")
```

- `where not A is null` -- prevents empty data to be used in query
- `count(D)` -- can count any column, that wasn't already used by query
- `group by B, C` -- must contain all selected items, except aggregates (count, sum, ets.)
- `pivot E` -- will make all answers to show in separate columns.

The result will look like this:

```
                    Left    Never   Right    Up
    Female  20-30      1        1             1 
    Female  30-40                       1   
    Male    20-30      1        1             1
    Male    30-40               1
```

Please, look at [complete Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Pivot Table function of Google Sheets?

- Download the data in excel format after the survey is complete and open with Google Sheets
- Select the tab with the resulting data from the Google Consumer Survey after it is run.
- From the menu, select Data -> Pivot Table. This opens a new tab in your spreadsheet.
- For the Values area of the pivot table, select User ID and from the "Summerize by" dropdown, select **COUNTUNIQUE**
- For the columns and rows, select whichever dimensions you are interested in. For instance, in your example, you would pick

"Gender" and "Answer 1" as a row and column. 
"Age" and "Answer 2" as a row and column.

This should answer these kinds of questions easily.

Hope this helps!

[image: You should get a pivot table that looks something like this]

Answer (score 0):

What I think I needed was the `COUNTIFS` function (in Google Sheets). Notice the plural use, which is different than `countif` (singular).

COUNTIFS allowed me to specify multiple criteria to make a score for each demographic segment. For example, I could count all the Males that responded Up in the answer 1 column.